# Enable svg, svgz mime type in IIS8

Tags: svg, gzip, mime-types, iis-8

I am using IIS 8 and MIME types are seemingly correctly configured in the IIS manager both globally and for my site.  However SVGs only get served as "document" and I cant serve svgz files at all (I get a parser error).

I have tried adding tricks like remove fileExtention, mimeMap in the web.config but that has no effect.  However if I leave out the remove tag in web.config and just try to map the filetype it gives an error, so IIS thinks the svg mimetype is mapped...  I have no idea how to solve this.